# Laravel 5.5 email confirmation and model adjustments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and I want newly registered users to activate their account by confirming their email address. Also, I need some extra fields or name alterations on the existent Laravel User model. `name` is replaced by `first_name` and `last_name`.

I found out that Laravel manages most parts of the registration in the `Auth/RegisterController` and so I modified what I needed:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:12',
        'first_name' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'terms' => 'accepted'
    ]);
}
```

The validator works fine, if I change the `first_name` `min:n`, it is correctly thereafter validated and shown to the user [the validation errors].

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'status' => 'inactive',
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'api_token' => static::generateApiKey(),
    ]);

    $activationLink = route('account.activation', static::generateRandomString());
    Mail::to($user)->send(new UserAccountConfirmationMail($user, $data['password'], $activationLink));
    return $user;
}
```

However, the creation (`create(array $data)`) does not work at all. I kind of feel like the code is not even executed (tried to add `dd` or `Log::info('...')` in order to find out whether or not it at all is executed) and nothing truly happens when I attempt to register. The page is sort of refreshed, however, no message on the user creation (if successful or not, ...), and subsequently no email in my box.

Am I missing out on some crucial detail here?

Comment: Did you change anything else by chance?

Comment: I assume you updated the user db scheme as well to reflect your changes?

Comment: you dont need to add stuff to that `create` method .. its "only" purpose is to create the user from the data it is given ... there is a `Registered` Event that gets fired when a user registers in modern versions of Laravel

Comment: Have you updated the $fillable property on the user model? When you comment out the activation link and email part what happens? Is the user created?

Comment: Okay, where is that `Registered` event in Laravel 5.5, @lagbox?

Comment: @Amade yes: `protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'api_token', 'status', 'profile_pic'
    ];`, which however is irrelevant when not even `$user = new User();` works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these days that you have spent hours on finding the errors has just finished. The `validator`, of which I thought was all fine because it was ordinarily displaying the errors, has been the turning point. I forgot to remove `name` from the validation. However, this validation error was never shown to me since I only caught these errors on display that I truly needed.

Solution:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:12',
    'first_name' => 'required|string|min:2',
    'last_name' => 'required|string|min:2',
    'terms' => 'accepted'
]);
```